# Boldface "Table" in caption of longtable, using the svjour3 document class

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I am using the [svjour3](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/svjour3-(springer-journals)) class to submit a tex document to a Springer journal. In this class, table captions appear like this:

> **Table 1** An example of a Table caption

If I use longtable however, I get captions like this:

> Table 2: An example of a Longtable caption

How can I make longtable captions consistent with the table captions of svjour3? I.e., I would like the latter example to appear like so:

> **Table 2** An example of a Longtable caption

that is, use boldface and remove the ":".

Since this is going to be sent for review, it is also important that *whatever change I do is for longtables only, and does not mess with Springer's document class.*

EDIT: I just found out that if I add this to the preamble does the job:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,small,labelsep=space]{caption}
```

This changes the other captions as well, making them however exactly the same as the original ones from the document class. Given that I'm submitting this to a journal, is it a good idea to go with that solution?

Comment: I wonder if it is worthwhile to add tags like "caption", "svjour3", or "springer". I couldn't do it due to my low reputation.

Comment: The persons able to answer your last edited in question really would somebody from the submission office. But since your code will most likely be re-processed anyway, there is no real use in bothering about it.

Answer (score 3):

I redefined `\LT@makecaption` from `longtbale` so as to typeset the captions in a similar way that `svjour3` typesets table captions:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \captionstyle
    \sbox\@tempboxa{{\floatlegendstyle#1{#2}\floatcounterend}\capstrut #3}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
      {\floatlegendstyle#1{#2}\floatcounterend}\capstrut #3\par%
    \else
      \hbox to\hsize{\leftlegendglue\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \hss}}}
\LTcapwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{a test regular table}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
test & test \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{longtable}{ | c | c |}
\caption{test longtable caption and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words and some more words} \\
test & test \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are submitting this to a journal, however, the staff will most surely process your document and produce the desired result in any case, so I don't think that you should bother with the redefinition.

Regarding the use of the `caption` package, I don't think you should load it; the very package will issue a warning when loaded with `svjour3`:

```
Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended.
```

Again, the journal staff most surely will make all the adjustments needed to your captions.